# In General what is the conditional density of Y given X=i when Y is continuous and X is discrete.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need help understanding why it would be the case that $$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid i)=\frac{P(X=i\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)}{P(X=i)}.$$ Though I've just started studying conditional distributions, I am comfortable working in either the discrete case or the continuous case, however this has thrown me for a loop. I've spent a few hours trying to find a way to establish the identity using what I know in general, but that's proved futile. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just conditional probability and the limit definition of derivative.

$$\begin{align}
f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid k) & = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf d y} \mathsf P(Y\leq y\mid X=k)
\\[1ex] & = \lim_{\delta y\to 0}\frac{\mathsf P(Y\leq y+\delta y \mid X=k)-\mathsf P(Y\leq y \mid X=k)}{\delta y}
\\[1ex] & = \lim_{\delta y\to 0}\mathsf P(y\lt Y\leq y+\delta y \mid X=k)/\delta y
\\[1ex] & = \lim_{\delta y\to 0}\frac{\mathsf P(X=k\mid y\lt Y\leq y+\delta y) \;\mathsf P(y\lt Y\leq y+\delta y)}{\mathsf P(X=k)\quad\delta y} 
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(X=k \mid Y=y) }{\mathsf P(X=k)}\frac{\mathsf d\;}{\mathsf d y}\mathsf P(Y\leq y)
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(X=k \mid Y=y) \, f_Y(y)}{\mathsf P(X=k)}
\end{align}$$